# How can I simulate MS Access 2013 in order to make sure my DB is compatible?

Tags: ms-access, compatibility, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I built a db for MS Access 2016 (both front end and back end) and it has grown to be very extensive (130+ queries, 50+ reports, etc...), but I have just stumbled upon a user whose copy of the DB isn't working because of compatibility issues.

I was wondering if there was a setting in the menu that might make the DB think it is running version 2013. This would help me with the present problem of adjusting the current DB to accommodate this user.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to download the free Access 2013 runtime and test in a VM using VirtualBox or VMWare etc. It is known to be difficult/impossible to run multiple versions of Access side by side. Link to runtime here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=39358

Comment: This is probably too broad for Stack Overflow: Asking for open tips without describing the particular compatibility issue.  Perhaps it's a better question for the Database Administrators group on Stack Exchange.  The fact that you admit there being many articles online does not necessarily make the topic or question bad for Stack Overflow--maybe you can eventually answer the question yourself, but it still seems odd to admit that your own research on the problem is only half baked. The general consensus on SO is to post **details** of a problem **and what you have already tried**.

Answer (score 2):

The generally accepted solution is to ALWAYS develop with the lowest common version. Access handles and works VERY well when moving forward, but not backwards. After all, a very old computer might not even have windows or a mouse – you can’t expect it to run modern software.

So the general approach is to develop in 2013, or even 2010. The resulting compiled accDE you distribute to each workstation will in near all cases run without issue. So there is no “switch” or some such. If the lowest common version of Access is 2013, then that is the development edition you should work with. Thus users with 2013, or 2016 should not have any issues.

Of course the other tip is to split your database (you clearly done that). And ensure that each workstation receives a copy of the front end (application part). So keep in mind that you don’t want to open + use a single deployed front end with “different” versions of Access. Following the above simple approach should result in a trouble free deployment approach and allow the two versions of Access to work without issues.

edit:
Also, if you have any references to a particular version of outlook, Excel, word etc., then you need to remove those references and adopt late binding.